# Lists and Dictionary inside Dictionary - how to store in excel sheet?

Tags: python, excel, list, dictionary

### Lists and Dictionary inside Dictionary

```
data ={

'name': 'ppp',

'foundationIp':'10.10.10.11',

'SourceUnit': {'id': '1',  'ip':'10.10.10.12', 'name':'qqq'},

'config': {'vendor': 'XXX', 'model': 'YYY', 'packages':[  {   'id': 'abc',
                'attributes': { 'ip': '10.10.10.13', 'user':'abc', 'password':'jikjh', 'timeout':20  }  }  ]  }

}
```

I'm looking to read in an Excel workbook with 50 rows, and convert each row to the above data structure in Python. 
I want to retrieve the data in the same format when I read the data from an excel sheet. Can someone please help me how to save the above data structure in an excel sheet and the way to retrieve (basically read operation) it ?

First thing is there a way to save and retrieve the above data structure in the same format from an excel sheet. (Adding data to the excel sheet can also be done manually).

Any help would be much useful.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You might find success in using win32com module from pywin32 (python extensions for windows) to create or connect to an excel application. You can then use the COM connection to manipulate the excel document as you would in VBA. So using this, you could iterate through your dictionaries to dump or read to/from excel. Sorry for the quick comment, short of time - hopefully others can expand on this :).

Comment: can you show some sample output? The way you want the excel to look like?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you want to do.  You say you want to read data from Excel into that data structure - is this an existing Excel file you need to read, or one you want to create?  Where and how is the original source data stored?

Comment: @TimWilliams Hi Tim, Basically I want to post that data in that json format to an application using Rest API. That Rest API requires the data to be in that given format. Now it is a repetitive task where in I have to post the data say 40-50 times depending on the customer needs). So I assumed it would be better to store all the data in an excel sheet and retrieve from the excel sheet in the same format. So my question is What could be the possible way to store this data in an excel sheet, so that when I retrieve, it should be in the same format? How should I save this data in the excel sheet?

Comment: You can store the data in a cell as json text.

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve].